# Bitbucket API endpoint for rerun stopped steps

Tags: api, rest, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-cloud

To stop a pipeline bitbucket REST API provides an endpoint repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/pipelines/{pipeline_uuid}/stopPipeline/, but there is no endpoint to rerun the pipeline from where the pipeline has stopped. So, is there any other way to rerun the stopped steps using another approach?

Found that no endpoint is currently there to rerun the stopped steps.

Comment: Bitbucket's Slack bot has a re-run widget for failed pipelines that does not work (it runs new unrelated pipelines) so I bet the answer is NO. Then a follow-up question could be... is their web UI using a different API?

Comment: Their web UI does not make any requests to other APIs.